# Enable Parse Server Push Notifications after Elastic Beanstalk deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I've been able to successfully deploy Parse Server to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the button on https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example, update my iOS client with the appropriate custom ParseClientConfiguration, and create a _PushStatus document on my mLab managed mongoDB through a curl request. However, when I do the latter, my sample iOS device does not receive a APNS Push Notification. How do I add a .p12 certificate and specify my bundle id and development status on EB (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Push#2-configure-parse-server)?

Comment: did you find an answer to this? Trying the same...